# Missing Doctype HTML Deployment using apache mod_proxy

Tags: html, apache, tomcat, doctype, mod-proxy

I have a strange problem...

My Vaadin Application is working fine on my computer (locally). I just deployed the website and now I have a problem:

The `<!Doctype html>` tag in the first line is missing. I don't know why it is, but I think this is causing some problems, because the Website is being displayed in Quirks mode.

The funny thing is, when I run the application locally, the doctype tag is set.

I simply exported the application to a war file and deployed it.

I haven't found any soloution on the Internet so far...

Is this a Tomcat setting problem or anything else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Already found the problem!

I was using Apache `mod_proxy` to handle my web application. The html doctype was not set in the `proxy_html.conf`. I simply had to define the `ProxyHTMLDocType` to HTML 5 in the `proxy_html.conf`.

`proxy_html.conf`:

```
ProxyHTMLDocType "<!DOCTYPE html>" // Sets the Doctype to HTML5
```

for further information just see:

http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/762/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this as an answer (I still cant comment posts :( ), but please make sure your local tomcat and production tomcat are the same version. You could also try not to package your project as a war file, but stop the server (if you are permitted of course) and copy the project yourself to make sure this is not a war-packaging issue